# Is it possible to have predefined Input with class AND Fontawesome?

Tags: html, css, input, font-awesome

my question is kinda dumb, but I don't really understand this Fontawesome thing.
So what I want to do is to put some Icons in this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/cea00496c5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
    input.knopf {
        background-color: #f4511e;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 32px;
        margin: 0px 0px;
        opacity: 0.3;
        transition: 1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 25px;
    }
    input.knopf:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: #f4511e;
        color: white;
    }
    input.knopf2 {
        background-color: lightseagreen;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 32px;
        margin: 0px 0px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        transition: 1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 25px;
    }

    input.knopf2:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: lightseagreen;
        color: white;
    }
    input.knopf3 {
        background-color: blueviolet;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 32px;
        margin: 0px 0px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        transition: 1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 25px;
    }

    input.knopf3:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: blueviolet;
        color: white;
    }
    input.knopf4 {
        background-color: blue;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 32px;
        margin: 0px 0px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        transition: 1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 25px;
    }

    input.knopf4:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: deepskyblue;
        color: white;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Wählen Sie aus in welchem Thema Sie Hilfe brauchen</h1>

        <table>
            <form></form>
            <tr>
        <th><input class="knopf " type="button"  value="Microsoft Outlook" onclick="window.location.href='#'"/></th>
        <th><input class="knopf2" type="button" value="Microsoft Word" onclick="window.location.href='/site/wiki/Seiten/Word%20Tastenk%c3%bcrzel.aspx'"/></th>
        <th><input class="knopf3" type="button" value="Microsoft Excel" onclick="window.location.href='/site/wiki/Seiten/Excel%20Tastaturk%c3%bcrzel.aspx'"/></th>
        <th><input class="knopf4" type="button" value="Zugriffsberechtigungen" onclick="window.location.href='/site/wiki/Seiten/Benutzerantrag%20Rollen%c3%bcbersicht.aspx'"/></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <th><input class="knopf4" type="button" value="SharePoint" onclick="window.location.href='/site/wiki/Seiten/SharePoint.aspx'"/></th>
        <th><input class="knopf3" type="button" value="SAP" onclick="window.location.href='/site/wiki/Seiten/SAP%20Schulungen.aspx'"/></th>
        <th><input class="knopf2" type="button" value="Facilitymanagement" onclick="window.location.href='/site/wiki/Seiten/Hausmeister.aspx'"/></th>
        <th><input class="knopf" type="button" value="Skype for Business" onclick="window.location.href='/site/wiki/Seiten/Skype%20for%20Business.aspx'"/></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th><input class="knopf2" type="button" value="Drucken" onclick="window.location.href='#'"/></th>
        <th><input class="knopf" type="button" value="Mobile Geräte" onclick="window.location.href='#'"/></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

as you can see I defined with CSS the style of my buttons. The Text of the Button is with "Value=""" made. How can I put some fontawesome icons in this box? I have literally no idea. I tried to declare more classes to input but it didnt work.

Comment: Take a look at https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/

Comment: or if you are using Fontawesome 5 then take a look at https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO Troi.

You can either display the icon in your button via your CSS by using the `:before` pseudo-selector to add the icon to your button or you can put the icon inside your button in the HTML like so:

```
<button class="knopf2" onclick="window.location.href='/site/wiki/Seiten/Word%20Tastenk%c3%bcrzel.aspx'"><i class="fa fa-home"> Microsoft Word</button>
```

Noticed that I have used a modern `button` element rather than an input because if you are learning it is a good practice to get into.